# scala auto convert functions / methods?

Tags: scala, traits

I have got a class with many methods.

```
class C{
def f1(x:String,....):...=..
def f2(..)...
.
.
.

}
```

I want now that every method defined in my class is decorated with a trait of my choice automatically.
Something like to create a tricky implicit ore something what decorates every method and perhaps returns an instance of the class with decorated methods. Perhaps wrapped or modified or something. I can not describe more of the way because i dont know the way.
 Do you know a way to do that?

Comment: I know methods can't be "decorated with a trait".

Comment: The question isn't clear enough to be answered.  What does it mean for every X to have Y of your choice "automatically"?  How do you indicate your choice if it's automatic?  Your class as written has methods but no functions.  Methods can't be decorated by traits.  What is your use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods are not functions, although they will automatically be lifted when you pass them to a method that requires a function. See also http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2009/05/scala-functions-vs-methods.html

If you really have functions:

```
class C {
  val f1 = (x: String, ...) =>
  val f2 = (...) =>
  ...
}
```

and you want them to mix in a trait, like:

```
class C {
  val f1 = new FunctionN[String, ...] with Gaga {
    def apply(s: String, ...) = ...
  }
  val f2 = new FunctionN[...] with Gaga { ... }
  ...
}
```

the only way I can think of is submit your class to something like Scala-Refactoring: http://scala-refactoring.org/